# Testing Grids in a Testing Notebook

Tags: testing-and-verification

I have an issue testing functions that generate formatted output. For example:

1) Create a new testing notebook and a new test like this:

[image: unevaluated test]

2) Now execute the test (it fails as expected)

[image: executed test]

3) Now click the "Replace Output" button and run it again:

[image: failing test]

Why is it failing? Lets show the cell expressions to see if there is a hidden difference:

[image: test showing expressions]

I don't see any significant difference. So my question is: is this a bug or should I do something different when testing functions that generate grids?

In the meanwhile, I have found that this works:

[image: testing redered views]

Testing functions that generate grids fails in this simple example:

Comment: There seem to be quite a few bugs with the Actual Output -> Expected Output pipeline in testing notebooks. This looks like another one. Another one is this: "\[LeftDoubleBracket]" becomes "[["...