# Testing Graphics in a Testing Notebook

Tags: testing-and-verification

Testing Notebooks report the result of `Plot` as a Failure, when in fact it should be a Success.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar issue to [Testing Grids in a Testing Notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101550/testing-grids-in-a-testing-notebook) and has the same solution: add a `{SameTest -> (Rasterize[#1] == Rasterize[#2] &)}`.

[image]

Seems related to the issue raised in [Testing equality of graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165652/testing-equality-of-graphics).

Comment: +1. It does seem inconvenient to have to do this.  (Note that rasterizing on tests approximate equality only. E.g. `Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x] + 10^-5, {x, 0, 10}]] == Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]`.)

Comment: I wonder why it fails. `CellChangeTimes`? Or something silly like that? Imo a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Digging around using `FullForm[]`shows that the difference is a string-valued private tag

```
`Charting`Private`Tag$[random number]
```

Therefore, we may manually set that tag number to, say, 1 via a rule

```
nullRule = x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "Charting`Private`Tag$*"] -> 
   "Charting`Private`Tag$1";
```

then the test runs okay:

[image]

Comment: also: does not work with pasted-in figure as expected output; also strongly suggest compare the data using, e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125222

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165652/testing-equality-of-graphics for the same solution and others.